# Alignment against parent div with CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css, alignment, center

I'm working on a little project for my buddy's band and recently switched to a new navbar. How it's layed out is that the logo is in the center, and the page links are to the left/right of it. So far that's working fine, but I wanted to add some text or maybe an image to the right and can't figure out how to do this as the navbar is set to center everything. Example shown in image here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqB4h.jpg

Keep in mind this navbar always stays on the top of the screen.

Here's what it looks like at the moment, had to use span2 to

CSS:

```
.fixed-nav-bar {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      z-index: 9999;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: #000;
      display: table;
}
span2 {
      display: table-cell;
      vertical-align: middle;
      position: relative;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<nav class="fixed-nav-bar">
<style>
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color:000;

}

li {
    display: inline-block;
}

li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}
</style><span2>
<ul><center>
  <li><a class="active" href="#Home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#About">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#Video">Video</a></li>
  <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/8Iu55Ho.png"></li>
  <li><a href="#Music">Music</a></li>
  <li><a href="#Press">Press</a></li>
  <li><a href="#Contact">Contact</a></li></center>
</ul></span2>
</nav>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: One trick you could use is to add a navbar to a table with 3 columns that are dristributed 25% 50% 25%. Add a navbar in the middle column and your "text" to the right column.

Comment: There is no such element as `<span2>`, `<center>` has been deprecated and should no longer be used..and in any event is not permitted as a child of a `ul`. ...oh and it doesn't have a corresponding closing tag *even if it wasn't deprecated*. Basically, the HTML structure is completely invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your `ul` to stay on center of page i think you have to use `position: absolute` for text on **right** side so it goes out of elements flow. So it should look something like this

```css
nav {
  position: fixed;
  background: black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

a {
  color: white;
  padding: 0 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-inner {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 20px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

img {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="nav-inner">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href=""><img src="http://i.imgur.com/8Iu55Ho.png"></a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
    
    <div class="text">Lorem ipsum</div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks!